# Add servlet filter to Neoj4 server (v2.1.5)

Tags: neo4j, servlet-filters

I'm developing an unmanaged extension for Neo4j.I get start with the [tutorial](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/server-unmanaged-extensions.html#server-unmanaged-extensions-streaming) and write a test unmanaged extension that works very well.

For some reasons,I need to add filter on requests.for example:

1. Execute request in transaction(like [OpenSessionIView](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/OpenSessionInView) in J2EE+Hibernate environment)
2. Convert some chareters(like [UpperCaseFilter](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0400__Servlet/Filterthatusesaresponsewrappertoconvertalloutputtouppercase.htm))
3. ...

Some people have same problem and suggest using PluginLifecycle([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26198341/neo4j-unmanaged-extension-and-guardtimeoutexception),[2](http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2013/07/08/neo4j-unmanaged-extension-creating-gzipped-streamed-responses-with-jetty/)). But my Neo4j version is 2.1.5 and this class was deprecated.

Is there any better way to add servlet filter to Neo4j server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use it, the deprecation has documentation purposes but the class will stay there until there is an alternative.